# Offline IE testing VM's

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, modern.ie

We are wanting to use the IE testing VM's to test our web applications across all versions of IE/Edge.  Now to keep the machine powered on they have to be activated, however this never succeeds since we are on a standalone network.  Is there an easy way to do this, or to contact someone who might know?  They are very useful, but our developers do not like having to get us to power them on when they power off after an hour.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know Microsoft offers VMs for testing IE/EDGE which can be user 60 or 90 days. I don't think that they require activation.

Comment: Not a good question for Stack Overflow. Probably better suited for [su] or [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bogdan said you should be able to use the VMs provided on https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/ They are free and expire after 90 days but the documentation mentions the following:

> Please note that these virtual machines expire after 90 days. We
>   recommend setting a snapshot when you first install the virtual
>   machine which you can roll back to later.

For testing Edge on Windows 10 please be aware of the following issue:

> Known issues: Windows 10 virtual machines may display a message in the
>   Settings app that reads “Connect to the Internet to activate.” This is
>   due to a bug and does not impact the activation state or functionality
>   of the virtual machine.

So you should be able to use the VMs for testing even without activating them and you can use them for more than 90 days by setting them back to a snapshot you created.